# Undefined constructor at Constants.java

Tags: java, android

In the fragment class inside Asynctask I am getting a constructor undefined error.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
 ..............
 .............
File file = new File(Constants.getAudioStoragePath()); --->Undefined constructor


//this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created

FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

}
```

**Constants.java:**

```
public static File getAudioStoragePath(Context context, String folderName) throws IOException {
    File baseFolder =  getFolder(context, "audio");
    File folder = new File(baseFolder, folderName);
    if (!folder.exists())  folder.mkdirs();
    return folder;
}
```

Anyone can help me with this what parameter I have to pass it.Thank you.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html. wrong params for constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the [answer of Johan Prins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28643473/1321873), pass appropriate parameters like:

`File file = Constants.getAudioStoragePath(getActivity(), "myFolder");`

Answer (score 1):

File does not contain a constructor that takes a File object.

Replace the one line of code with this:

```
File file = Constants.getAudioStoragePath();
```

Note that you will also need to update you Constants class to contain a getAudioStoragePath() method that takes no parameters.

The above will fix your "undefined constructor" error. Your next problem will most likely be when you create a FileOutputStream. Your file that you get from constants is actually a directory, if I read this code correctly. You need to create a File inside the Directory that you write to.

Comment: @Rajesh is correct. You will also need to define a getAudioStoragePath() method that takes no parameters. This will typically return the base directory (in this case)